# Split a pandas dataframe into two dataframe based on values in a columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, let's say:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1 , 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'val1': [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'val2': [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4]})`

I want to split it into two dataframes,(`train`, and `test`) using the values in the `id` column. The split should be such that in the first dataframe I have 80% of the  (unique) `id`s and in the second dataframe, I have 20% of the `id`s. The `id`s should be randomly splitted.

My own attempt:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
def train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, prng_seed=None):
    prng = random.Random()
    prng.seed(prng_seed)
    id_list = df['id'].unique().tolist()
    prng.shuffle(id_list)
    id_size = len(id_list)
    test_abs_size =  int(id_size * test_size)
    test_id = id_list[-test_abs_size:]
    train_id = id_list[:-test_abs_size]
    train_data = df[df['id'].isin(train_id)]
    test_data = df[df['id'].isin(test_id)]
    return train_data, test_data
```

Comment: But the `id`s occur multiple times?

Comment: It sounds like you want to apply stratification such that the distribution of customer ids is preserved: train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, stratify=df.id)

Answer (score 1):

The following code splits the dataset into 80-20 train-test sets

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2)
```

Per @JanTrienes comment, if you want to preserve the distribution of `id`s, you can use `stratify` The following code exectues that:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4,
                          1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
                 'val1': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3,
                          1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                 'val2': [3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4,
                          3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4]})

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, stratify=df.id)
```

Here is an example of what the output would be:

```
train:
    id  val1  val2
0    1     1     3
7    4     3     4
15   4     3     4
13   3     1     3
14   4     2     4
11   2     1     4
9    1     2     3
8    1     1     3
12   2     2     4
4    2     2     4
2    2     1     4
5    3     1     3
test:
    id  val1  val2
6    4     2     4
10   2     1     4
1    1     2     3
3    2     1     4
```

Comment: In my problem setting, I am interested in unique ids, you can think of them as customer ids, I want to train on the data from 80% of the customers and test on the remaining 20% of the customers.

Comment: @user128751 is it acceptable to remove duplicate IDs prior to splitting into training and testing sets?

Comment: @user128751 does my most recent edit answer your question? If not, could you add an example of the desired output you are looking for?